# How to: activate .overlay in swift ui button action

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

Looking to give my Button() a border using .overlay when it is clicked. I am approaching this feature using a @State var `@State var isActive = false`

I haven't figured out the correct approach yet related to "deactivating" the border when the button is not selected.

Here is an example `HStack` with buttons setup... Is `.overlay` the correct approach? I am looking for a white border around the button..

```
HStack(spacing: 1) {
                    
 Button("App\nHelp", action: {print("app help"); self.isActive = true})
                        .foregroundColor(.white).font(Font.body.bold())
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity).padding(.vertical, 15)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.yellow))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
 Button("More\nApps", action: {print("more apps")})
                        .foregroundColor(.white).font(Font.body.bold())
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity).padding(.vertical, 15)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.red))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood your goal here is a demo of possible approach using custom button style.

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
Button("Demo") {}
    .buttonStyle(ActiveBorderStyle())
```

and style itself

```
struct ActiveBorderStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.blue).padding()
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke().foregroundColor(
                configuration.isPressed ? .blue : .clear))
    }
}
```

Comment: what if all buttons dont hold the same style values?

Comment: It is just struct - you can add properties to it and inject needed parameters when construct.

Answer (score -1):

Archived the feature by following @Asperi 's suggestion above with a little modification..

```
      Button("More\nApps", action: {print("more apps"); self.isActiveMoreApps = true; self.isActiveAppHelp = false})
                        .foregroundColor(.white).font(Font.body.bold())
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity).padding(.vertical, 15)
                        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.red))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        
                       .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke().foregroundColor(
                       isActiveMoreApps ? .white : .red))
```

Each button will receive a state variable that gets activated in the action. To remove the border from the button you previously selcted make sure to set that buttons variable back to `false`